# mfc directory picker?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I did see this to modify CFileDialog (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105497) but it looks like a lot more than I need.

I'm using the CFileDialog to pick files, is there a simple way to use it to just select a directory?

Any other suggestions?

(I also saw this but is for XP only?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163948%28office.10%29.aspx)

(VS 6.0 C++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably want to use the [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115(VS.85).aspx) API.  There are lots of wrapper classes out there that make it easier to use.  Like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FolderBrowse.aspx) one.

Answer (score 2):

[Dundas Ultimate Toolbox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox.aspx) has a folder selection drop-down tree. It is nice because you don't need to open a new window just for selecting a folder.

The class is defined in FolderTree.h and is called CFolderTree.